# How can I make a TeX file executable?

Tags: catcodes, scripts, unix

Under UNIX, to my knowledge, any regular file can be made executable with the addition of a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)):

```sh
#! /path/to/executing-program --with --options
```

How can I apply the same principle to a TeX file without altering syntax rules for the entire document?

```sh
$ cat > tmp.tex
#! /usr/bin/env tex --mystery --options
hello, world
\bye
$ chmod +x tmp.tex
$ ./tmp.tex
$ dvi2tty -q tmp.dvi | grep .
hello, world
                                   1
$ logout
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is file `seanenv.tex`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env pdflatex \catcode35=14 \input
\catcode`\#=6
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello, Sean!
\end{document}
```

After `chmod u+x seanenv.tex`, I can issue

```
./seanenv.tex
```

and the `seanenv.pdf` file is compiled.

Note that 35 is the character code of `#`, which must be made into a comment character before TeX rereads the file. After this, `#` is given back its category code 6.

This is not limited to `pdflatex`; the same strategy will work with `tex` and so on.

Comment: strange that's what I tried but on cygwin it just hangs, no log no error no termination. I couldn't inject any amount of quoting to make it work. (I somehow doubt you tested cygwin:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Does Cygwin full support file permissions?  I know that the underlying Windows system doesn't, really...

Comment: See also [this additional answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/216018/17423)

Comment: This _may_ work, but is not guaranteed to: The [Sheebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) MUST handle only one argument to the command (which is `/usr/bin/env` in your case) - the handling of more arguments is highly non-portable.

Comment: @MartinSchröder I agree with you; this seems to work on the Unix systems where I tested it (Mac OS X and GNU/Linux). However, `env` allows `env utility argument ...`, at least on a POSIX compliant system.

Answer (score 12):

It hangs for me as well. Changing the first line to use the path to pdflatex (instead of going via /usr/bin/env) fixes it for me:

```
#! /bin/pdflatex \catcode35=14 \input
```

Change /bin/pdflatex if needed to the full path for pdflatex. The command:

`which pdflatex`

will tell you what this is.

Comment: curious for me on cygwin that runs but it always runs plain tex not latex (so it's not picking up the command name correctly to default the format) so finally this works `#!  /usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-cygwin/pdflatex &latex \catcode35=14 \input`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  Thanks for the additional information :)

Comment: @SeanAllred Your link __our starter guide__ leads to a website that can’t provide a secure connection. It uses an unsupported protocol. The client and server don't support a common SSL protocol version or cipher suite.

Comment: @JohnGoofy I fixed the link, thanks!